# Typescript: How to use Generic Type in functions

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following structure:

```
export interface Complex {
    getId<T>(entity: T): string
}

const test: Complex = {
    getId<Number>(entity){return "1"} // does not work 'entity is implicitly any'
}
```

Why do I have to declare the type of `entity` as `entity:Number` in order to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you declare interface which has a Generic Type Function (`getById`).

To reference to generic as a type, you must do this:

```
interface Complex<T> {
  getId(entity: T): string;
}

const test: Complex<Number> = {
  getId(entity) {
    return entity.toString();
  }
}
```

The use-case of what you did might be following:

```
interface AbstractFactory {
  create<T>(data: T): string;
}

const factory: AbstractFactory = {
  create<T>(data: T): string {
    return data.toString();
  }
}

factory.create<Number>(123);
```

Comment: I purposely only want to give the function the generic type and not the whole interface. My function above works as long as I declare `entity:Number`, but why do I have to do that.

Comment: Because that `Number` is not a type, but the name for the generic parameter. This might be any other word as well.